# Why is stack undefined after calling new Error()

Tags: node.js, error-handling, visual-studio-code

I have a service that I'm writing with Node.js and Express and I've run into a problem where errors are not carrying a stack trace on their `.stack` property as one would expect when looking at the error object through the *WATCH* window in VSCode. Instead my error object's stack property is `undefined`. Additionally calling `console.error(err)` outputs the error information in the *DEBUG CONSOLE* window but doesn't have any of the stack details.

I've been looking through documents and all indications are that calling `new Error("My message")` should create an Error object that has a stack that represents the call stack up to the point where the error object was instantiated.

I'm using *Node v4.2.2* on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Error` object won't report the stack when you call `.toString()` on it, and this is what gets called when you `console.log(err)`.

This is because [the stack isn't generated until the `.stack` attribute is accessed](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack).

> The string representing the stack trace is lazily generated when the error.stack property is accessed.

To see the full stack, including the error message, use `err.stack` directly:

`console.log(err.stack)`

I do this in my node code anytime I need the error message and stack.